# FormAuthentication not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a site in ASP.NET MVC. Unfortunately the  `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, login.RememberMe);`doesn't seem to work properly.

**Edit**: this is the code I am using:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login, string returnUrl) {
     if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) {
               return Redirect(returnUrl);
            } else {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
          }
     }
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password are incorrect!");
   return View(login);
}
```

I've set authentictation to Forms in my config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login"/>
</authentication>
```

When I try to logout, it always redirects me to login, as the server thinks I'm not logged in.
I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point it out? I already did some research but non of the answers answered my question/problem.

I also have the following code in a partial, which doesn't work either.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    //show logout button
} 
else 
{ 
    //show login button

}
```

Comment: How your are storing the cookies ?

Comment: You say "When you try to logout". When you logout, where are you redirecting to? If the page you are redirecting to requires authentication, the server will automatically redirect to the login page again.

Comment: I never go into logout, because the user doesn't seem to be authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working, I simply had to add the following tags to the web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

and

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```